# COPY INTO with partitioned Azure External Storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a container with partitioned parquet files that I want to use with the copy into command. My directories look like the below.

```
corporate_sales ==> Container 
dimension ===> Folder
region  ==> Sub Folder
99424-0191019-snappy.parquet
99434-0191020-snappy.parquet
salesperson ==> SubFolder
99425-0191021-snappy.parquet
99426-0191022-snappy.parquet
facts ==> Folder
sales
2022 ==> Year Sub Folder
12   ==> Month Sub Folder
01   ==> Day Sub Folder
SALES-99499-0191022-snappy.parquet
```

How do I create an optimal External Stage on the Azure Storage ?
Is this normal practice ?

```
create stage my_azure_stage
  storage_integration = azure_int
  url = 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/load/corporate_sales/'
  file_format = my_parquet_format;
```

How do I properly use the pattern parameter in the copy into command to write to a SF table from my Blob Storage?

In the above example I would like to take the files in the region folder and load into Region SF Table dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are under different folders and you cannot set a pattern to ingest them, you can then create different storage integration for different folders and point to the sub-folders which have the files.
You will only be scanning the directories present there and not the entire storage, this will reduce the latency and will also optimize the cost.

You can also use partitioning in case you have files getting loaded into storage with some prefix like Day\time etc.

With the URL mentioned in your COPY INTO statement
url = 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/load/corporate_sales/'
This will scan all the folders inside the Corporate_sales and load the files from each folder.
So if you only want Region folder files to be added just create a Storage Integration pointing to the Region folder and when you run COPY INTO, the files inside the Region folder will be added to SF table.

Hope this answers your query.